# Pushing ajax object response into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

For some reason this does not loop through each object in my Ajax response into the array properly, I'm banging my head against a wall with this now.

My Ajax response is as follows...

```
{type:'blog_post',date:2013-30-12,title:'Blog Post',width:450,content:'qweqwe'},{type:'blog_post',date:2013-30-12,title:'Blog Post',width:450,content:'qweqwe'}
```

and here is the code...

```
var getTimelineData = function() {
    var tldata = [];
    $.get('/data/timeline_data', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, val) {
            tldata.push(val)
            console.log(val);
        });
    });
    return tldata;
};
```

The console log returns the exact response not as an individual array item.

Comment: Your AJAX response isn't an array.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is *asynchronous*!  When you call `$.get`, the AJAX call runs in the background and your code continues on.  Later on in the future, when the AJAX call done, your callback function is ran.  So, the `return tldata;` is run way before the AJAX call is finished.

You *cannot* return a value from an AJAX call, that's not how it works.  I suggest passing a callback to the `getTimelineData` function.  You can call it when the AJAX call is done:

```
var getTimelineData = function(callback) {
    $.get('/data/timeline_data', function(data) {
        var tldata = [];

        $.each(data, function(i, val) {
            tldata.push(val)
            console.log(val);
        });

        if($.isFunction(callback)){
            callback(tldata);
        }
    });
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
getTimelineData(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the JSON cheker available online could help you. I often use http://jsonlint.com/

In JSON an array is declared with [], so I suspect the ajax answer should be more :

```
[
    {
        "type": "blog_post",
        "date": "2013-30-12",
        "title": "BlogPost",
        "width": 450,
        "content": "qweqwe"
    },
    {
        "type": "blog_post",
        "date": "2013-30-12",
        "title": "BlogPost",
        "width": 450,
        "content": "qweqwe"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax response is invalid JSON. You should be wrapping it in [], if you want to return an array:

```
[{type:'blog_post',date:2013-30-12,title:'Blog Post',width:450,content:'qweqwe'},{type:'blog_post',date:2013-30-12,title:'Blog Post',width:450,content:'qweqwe'}]
```

Comment: Its not Json its a javascript array.